# Firebase Cloud Messaging send success but not receive message

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I got some problems with firebase cloud messaging.

When I got fcm token from the browser and send to API (Reactjs do this step)

API retrieved the fcm token and triggered messaging.send(payload)
it return success but the browser did not receive the message.

I try with CURL or Postman to send the same token and API and the browser received message.

I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

this is a video i reproduce: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/11322305?key=b50f900120942c92d5e62bd1fac37995

Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Probably, this is a duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46634261/firebase-messaging-web-receiving-message-does-not-work